Finding inner product value in QM given change of basis
Given the linear transformation
$x\rightarrow x'$
$y\rightarrow y'$
$z\rightarrow z'$
where $\{x', y', z'\}$ are linear combinations of $\{x,y,z\}$ 
How can I find the value
$\langle x',y',z'|x,y,z\rangle$
I have considered something along
$\delta (x-x')\delta (y-y')\delta (z-z')$
but this seems odd since $x'$, for example, could have a component in the $y$ direction, e.g. $x' = ax+by$
Also is there a general way to find the inner product of two kets? Or do we have to conduct an experiment to find the probability amplitudes? (unless we have specific prior knowledge).

This looks link and active/passive transformation issue. Is your linear transformation mapping your original point to a new point in the same coordinates or expressing the same point in a new set of coordinates

@BySymmetry the latter i believe? it's done to diagonalize the harmonic potential

Are you given the operator that does $(x',y',z') = A (x,y,z)$? If yes, aren't you just looking for $\langle x,y,z \vert A^* \vert x,y,z \rangle$. Also is the domain of $A$ specified?

@RefikMansuroglu Are you referring to the operator in the hilbert space
$|x,y,z>\rightarrow |x',y',z'>$
or the operator in $R^3$ :
$(x,y,z) \rightarrow (x'y'z')$
? I have the latter.
I agree that if we were talking about the former your formula would be correct, but how would I find it? If the matrix elements for the two are the same I could use a source that covers the subject :)

I understand. No, in general, there is no linear operator acting on a wave function such that $\hat A \psi(\vec x) = \psi(A \vec x)$. Still, the inner product that you are interested in can be executed in position basis and yields 0 whenever $(x',y',z') \neq (x,y,z)$ and 1 else.

Your equation is correct:
$\langle x', y', z' | x, y, z \rangle = \delta(x - x')\delta(y - y')\delta(z - z')$.
If any of $\{x, y, z\}$ changes under the linear transformation, then this inner product is zero.
